# The Guild's Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, pattern

A mighty warrior by the name of Stiv the Slayer has done enough by brawn to prove himself worthy of entering the Guild of 24/7rs. Now what is left is that he needs to prove that his brains are also up to standard so he is given a puzzle at the door. He, being over 9k iq works it out in seconds.

Can you work it out too?

Puzzle:

Please provide the missing answer.

R heart, for C

G and W wolf, for S

DB bow, for R

S shield, for D

W star, for P

LB fist,  for S

S sword,  for A

?

Hint:

> The introductory passage contains several hints but there is one very big hint in it.

> RGB and Icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the answer is

> B Hat, for M

> The descriptions seem to be of the icons of Combat skills in Runescape. Additionally, the rs in "Guild of 24/7rs" seems to be referring to RuneScape. 
>  Red Heart for Constitution 
>  Grey and White Wolf for Summoning 
>  Dark Brown Bow for Range 
>  Silver shield for Defence 
>  White star for Prayer 
>  Light Brown Fist for Strength 
>  Silver Sword for Attack

> The only one missing seems to be Blue Hat for Magic.

Comment: Congratulations!